# Scala: How do I check that a dynamically loaded class implements a trait?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, traits

I am trying to build a Scala application in which the user can load in classes that implement an interface defined by a trait, which the application will then use.

For example, my Operator trait

```
trait Operator {
    def operate(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}
```

is implemented by a user-defined class to be loaded in at run time, Add.

```
class Add {
  def operate(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

How can the application check that this Add class implements the Operator trait it knows about? I would like to be able to call `operate` on an instance of the loaded class.

I have tried simple pattern matching like this

```
case op: Class[Operator] => op.newInstance()
```

but this appears to check implementation based on trait name rather than member signatures.

Comment: member signatures ? your `Add` class does not implement the `Operator` trait.

Comment: "member signatures" is probably the wrong terminology. What I meant was that pattern matching is not checking that `Add` implements a function called `operate` with the appropriate parameter and output types.

I see that `Add` doesn't implement `Operator`, but including that does not seem to help. Importantly, I'm looking for a way in which the application and the Add class can be compiled independently, so the user writes a class that follows the Operator trait guidelines but does not have direct access to the application source code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to let `Add` implement `Operator`, instead of trying to come up with some duck-typing scheme?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, lets clear the terminology, your `class` `Add` simply does not `implement` the `Operator` trait which you defined. You should not and can not use clearly defined terms to mean something different compared to their actual meaning.

Now, what you are looking for are `structural types` and not `traits`.

Lets define a `strucural type` with name `IsOperator`,

```
type IsOperator = {
  def operate(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}
```

And lets define something logic which uses this,

```
def perform(a: Int, b: Int, o: IsOperator): Int = o.operate(a, b)
```

Now, any `object` or instance of any `class` which confirms to the `structural type` `IsOperate` (has a method named `operate` with type `(Int, Int) => Int`)  can be used with `perform`.

```
object Add {
  def operate(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}

val sum = perform(1, 2, Add)
// sum: Int = 3
```

Comment: Thank you! this is just what I was look for.

Comment: An important addition is that while Scala supports this, it doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: `main` is also just a method signature. That was also not a good idea...

Comment: Desperate times call for desperate measures.

Comment: So now how do you "check that a dynamically loaded class implements a [structural type]"? I guess by surrounding `o.operate(a, b)` with `try ... catch { case e: NoSuchMethodException => ... }`.

Comment: If the class is "dynamically loaded" the it will change things... perhaps `Try(asInstanceOf[IsOperator])`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I'm pretty sure `asInstanceOf` always succeeds for structural types which are refinements of `AnyRef`. It's only when you call the method that it will fail.

Comment: @Jasper-M Thanks for the info, I luckily/unluckily never encountered that.